# Arduino Relay Modulo stops working

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino controlling a lamp through a relay module, everything works fine for some hours, but now it stops working. The led to on/off as expected, but i cant hear the "click" anymore, and now it is always on.
A relay module can burn out? My lamp is 250w/110V

Comment: This is programming related site. Figuring out, if your relay died, is not.

Comment: i just wanna know if someone had the same issue, if you cannot help dont wast your time.

Comment: This isn't a forum. Just asking if anyone had the same issue is off-topic.

Comment: I know it is a programming related site, but once it has a Arduino tag i understand asking about circuit is on topic. If you are a moderator and wants to close my question go ahead. Anyway i solved my issue.

Comment: Hardware issues aren't programming-related. I'd consider https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ instead, or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, when it's a question explicitly about hardware, which this is.

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED: The issue was that i had others sensors connected to Arduino 5V output pin (the relays was already on a separated 5V), and that was getting current from arduino board causing arduino not able to turn on the relay coil.
After change sensor to use a separated 5V source (with more current) everything works fine again.

My advise: be careful to use arduino 5V or 3.3V as a source power because it has low current, causing errors or even restarting arduino.